# Speakker - Allow user to remove items from playlist

Tags: html5-audio, projekktor

Is there a way to allow the user to remove items from the speakker playlist?  I don't want to have to write a separate page that manages the playlist.

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at the docs. You could pass an array to the file parameter with the playlist.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      var pList = [
        {
         0: { 
            src: "http://uberelectron.s3.amazonaws.com/uberelectron1.mp4",
            type: "video/mp4"
           }, 
            config: {
            title: "Hello World.",
            poster: "uebere.png"
           }
        },
         { 
        0: {
           src: "intro.mp4",
           type: "video/mp4"
        },
           config: {
           title: "Intro, MP4 only"
        }
       }
      ];
  $().speakker({
     file: pList,
     playlist: true,
     theme: 'light',
     admin: 'http://www.speakker.com/opentape/code/login.php',
     lastfm: 'http://www.lastfm.de/music/paniq'
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, this isn't the information that I need.  I am aware that I can add files to the playlist externally, I want to know if there is a way to remove items from the playlist using the speakker GUI.